# Why is there an error loading a PDF using Intent on Android 7

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, mobile-browser

I have a TextView with an onClick event handler to download an open a PDF file

I have the following code in the response handler.

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdfUrl)))
```

I can see the PDF loading but before it can be read it returns to the app with the error below.

> Cannot open PDF
>
> <filename>.pdf cannot be opened

[image: Error message: (Cannot open PDF <filename>.pdf cannot be opened)]

Device properties

> ril.model_id: QB13532959
>
> ro.board.platform: exynos5
>
> ro.boot.em.model: SM-J327T1
>
> ro.build.version.sdk: 24
>
> ro.product.brand: samsung
>
> ro.product.manufacturer: samsung
>
> ro.product.model: SM-J327T1
>
> ro.product.name: j3popeltemtr

Comment: What is the exact value of `pdfUrl`?

Comment: It's a URL string that might identify the client. but it's in the form https://subdomain.client.com:<port>/<filename>.pdf

Comment: There is no requirement for an Android user to have an activity that supports `ACTION_VIEW` of a PDF located at an `https` URL. So, you are going to have problems with some users in general, even beyond this. In terms of this specific problem, my guess is that the PDF viewer on this device is either having difficulty completing the download of the PDF or parsing the PDF. You might see if Logcat has any messages from this PDF viewer that might give you more specific clues.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot right now. I assumed it found the PDF based on how it reacted but the file is loaded one level deeper. Thank you for the prompt.

Comment: Just my second week doing Android dev so I'm still feeling my way around.

Comment: @CommonsWare Shouldn't the browser handle that action due to the URI format?

Comment: It could. In this case, I'm assuming a PDF viewer responded, given that the error `Toast` mentions "PDF" by name. Android itself would have made a `HEAD` request to determine the MIME type for your URL and added that MIME type to your `Intent`, before finding possible matches. There might be 0, 1, or N activities that match. In the N case, if the user has said "Always" to some previous similar request, that past user selection becomes the activity that gets control. Otherwise, a chooser appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) I double-checked assumptions and realized there was an error with the PDF URL. The problem has been resolved.